# How to add a Header/Footer on a PDF File with DroidText?

Tags: android, pdf, android-droidtext

I want to add a Header or a Footer on the first page of my PDF.
I have tried to set it just after construct the Document. But, it was inneficient.

I also have thought of passing the first page and delete it at the end. But, I haven't managed it yet... :(

Has someone a solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Droidtext is based on an iText version that is no longer supported. It's not endorsed by the original authors of iText, please use the official Android port of iText: http://itextsupport.com/download/android.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code may useful to you:

**Set Header:**

```
//open the document
doc.open();

//set header
Phrase headerText = new Phrase("This is an example of a Header");
HeaderFooter pdfHeader = new HeaderFooter(headerText, false);
doc.setHeader(pdfHeader);
```

**Set Footer:**

```
//set footer
Phrase footerText = new Phrase("This is an example of a footer");
HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);

//close doc
doc.close();
```

Comment: Can I have a full code or any references. Please